# Could not establish an ssh connection on router using NETMIKO

Tags: python, networking, devops, paramiko, netmiko

I am trying to develop a python script that connect to cisco router through another router using netmiko( ConnectHandler()). ssh to R1 then SSH to R2 from R1.

I established the first connexion to R1 , and I used Netmiko to ssh to the router R2 But I could not establish the cnx.
**This is the dictionary creation**

```
def sh_route(self,alias):
    global verif
    self.device = self._cache.switch(alias)
    device_info = {
                'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
                'ip': self.device.hostname,
                'username': self.device.username,
                'password': self.device.password,}
```

**Connexion to R1 using ConnectHandler and the dictionary created**

```
#connect to device1 from linux
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device_info)
    ldp= self.get_ldp_neighbors(alias)
    for  x in ldp.keys():
        addr_list = ldp[x]['addresses'] #List of ldp ip adresses  
        
        src_ip_addr= ldp[x]['SrcIPaddr'] #source ip addr
```

**Writing ssh 'src_ip_addr  using write_channel() function'** (src_ip_addr is the address that I want to ssh)

```
            net_connect.write_channel('ssh'+src_ip_addr+'\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        output = net_connect.read_channel()
```

**use a loop for the above username and password handling**
The password seems like it was not written , so the cnx failed.

```
        i = 1
        while i <= 20:
            try:   
                if 'Username' in output:
                    net_connect.write_channel(net_connect.username + '\r\n')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    output = net_connect.read_channel()
                if 'password' in output:
                    net_connect.write_channel(net_connect.password + '\n')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    output = net_connect.read_channel()
                i += 1
            except EOFError:
                pass
            print(output=
```

**Verify that the cnx was establisged**

```
print ("SSH prompt: {}".format(net_connect.find_prompt()))
```

**then use the dispatch feature and send command to the destination router R2**

```
redispatch(net_connect, device_type='cisco_ios')
    net_connect.enable()
    new_output = net_connect.send_command('show version', use_textfsm=True)
```

**Then I tried to run the command sh ip route connected and sh route local**

```
        version= new_output[0]['rommon']
    if  version == 'IOS-XE':
        new_output = net_connect.send_command('show ip route connected')
        return new_output
    if  version == 'IOS-XR':
        new_output = net_connect.send_command('show route local')
        return new_output
```

THE problem is in the username and password handling section.

THis is the output on terminal

```
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
ssh 192.168.247.2
Password: 
SSH prompt: Password:
```

this is the full log:

THIS is the log

> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x31b464e0
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.7.2
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-Cisco-1.25
> INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client Cisco-1.25)
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1'] server key:['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa'] client encrypt:['aes128-gcm', 'aes256-gcm', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes128-gcm', 'aes256-gcm', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512'] server mac:['hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey agreed: ssh-rsa
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo 
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for Bnet-A101: b'a51ea5a576822573a37ce25441bd0241'
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
> INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 4096 bytes
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
> DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'terminal width 511\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: terminal width 511
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: CCCCCCCC

CC
C

---

|                                                                             |
|                    BNET-A101 at BRATISLAVA vLAB                             |
|                                                                             |
|         THIS IS A PRIVATE SYSTEM MANAGED BY ORANGE BUSINESS SERVICES        |
|                                                                             |
|        ACCESS TO THIS DEVICE REQUIRES AUTHENTICATION AGAINST THE            |
|                                                                             |
|                  >> LAB INFRASTRUCTURE TACACS SERVICE <<                    |
|                                                                             |
|                 Your "saturne" login should be used here                    |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|

> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: CCCCCCCC

CCCCCCCCCC
CC
C
________________________________________________________________
|                                                                |
|  Activity on this device is recorded and possibly monitored    |
|________________________________________________________________|

Bnet-A101#terminal width 5

> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: 11
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: terminal width 511 CCCCCCCC

CC
C

---

|                                                                             |
|                    BNET-A101 at BRATISLAVA vLAB                             |
|                                                                             |
|         THIS IS A PRIVATE SYSTEM MANAGED BY ORANGE BUSINESS SERVICES        |
|                                                                             |
|        ACCESS TO THIS DEVICE REQUIRES AUTHENTICATION AGAINST THE            |
|                                                                             |
|                  >> LAB INFRASTRUCTURE TACACS SERVICE <<                    |
|                                                                             |
|                 Your "saturne" login should be used here                    |
|                                                                             |
|                                                                             |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
CCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCC
CC
C
________________________________________________________________
|                                                                |
|  Activity on this device is recorded and possibly monitored    |
|________________________________________________________________|

Bnet-A101#terminal width 511

> DEBUG:netmiko:In disable_paging
> DEBUG:netmiko:Command: terminal length 0
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'terminal length 0\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: terminal\ length\ 0
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: Bnet-A101#
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: terminal len
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: gth 0
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: terminal\ length\ 0 Bnet-A101#terminal length 0
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:Bnet-A101#terminal length 0
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:Exiting disable_paging
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: Bnet-A101#

Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#

> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is Bnet-A101#
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'ssh 192.168.247.2\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: ssh 192.168.247.2

Password:

> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: CCCCAuthentication failed, please try again!

Password:

> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is Password:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: Bnet-A101
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: CCCCAuthentication failed, please try again!

Password:

DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: CCCCAuthentication failed, please try again!
Password:

> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data:
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data:

[Connection to 192.168.247.2 closed by foreign host]
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#

> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: Bnet-A101 CCCCAuthentication failed, please try again!

Password:
CCCCAuthentication failed, please try again!
Password:

[Connection to 192.168.247.2 closed by foreign host]
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#

> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:

Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#
Bnet-A101#

> DEBUG:netmiko:Clear buffer detects data in the channel
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:

Bnet-A101#

> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is Bnet-A101#
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'show version\n'
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: show\ version
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: s
> DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: how version
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: show\ version show version
>
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
> DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:

**output of sh ip route connected executed under R1 not R2**

Comment: I see too much of random code and output. If you need help, make your question concise and readable.